# Excel - Write a sum formula with a condition in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In this example I want to write a formula in the end of Col3 (C11), to calculate the total like this :

if the cell value in Col1 is less than the value in Col3, then take Col1 else take Col3 to calculate the total of Col3.

So, in my example, the total of Col3 is : 1960.95 + 2764.37 + 12500 + 5787.34 + 2582.09 + 12500 + 12500 + 499.98 = 51094.73

I wrote a code to get the sum. But is it possible to write a formula in C11?

```
Here is my example :
         A           B      C           D
         Col1        Col2   Col3        Col4
         1 960,95    0,00   12 500,00   0,00
         2 764,37    0,00   12 500,00   0,00
         20 584,38   0,00   12 500,00   8 084,38
         5 787,34    0,00   12 500,00   0,00
         2 582,09    0,00   12 500,00   0,00
         44 605,50   0,00   12 500,00   32 105,50
         44 602,50   0,00   12 500,00   32 102,50
         499,98      0,00   12 500,00   0,00

Total    123 387,11  0,00   51 094,73   72 292,38
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A9<C2:C9,A2:A9,C2:C9))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Would you care to elaborate on what an array formula is?

Comment: An array formula will create an array of values.  For example the IF Statement in this instance will create an array or group of numbers that satisfy the IF statment so {960.95,2764.37,12500,5787.34,2582.09,12500,12500,499.98}

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a solution of my problem. I don't want to sum all the values of the column, it is not sum(A2:A9) or sum(c2:C9)

Comment: It did what you asked, it only added those numbers that from col1 that where les than col3 otherwise it used col3 value.  @D.O.

Comment: @D.O. it iterates through each row and uses col1 only if it is less than the number in Col3 of that row.  If not it uses the value from col3 for that row.  It does not sum only all of one or the other, it will sum the correct values from either depending on the relationship of each row.

Comment: I have tried your formula, but it gives me an error, saying : can't evaluate if(A2:A9. is my Excel don't know about array formulas? I have Excel 10

Comment: You may need to change the `,` to `;` and make sure to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter. @D.O.

Comment: I have changed , to ;. the problem was with { }. Now it working. Also, I have found how to write an array formula in VBA. The cell has "FormulaArray" property. Il will use it in my VBA to see what it will be. Thanks!!!

Comment: in VBA the array formula must be written with RC, like : Range("C11").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(R[-9]C[-2]:R[-2]C[-2]<R[-9]C:R[-2]C,R[-9]C[-2]:R[-2]C[-2],R[-9]C:R[-2]C))"

Answer (score 1):

You could just create Col5 with the formula `=IF(A2<C2,A2,C2)` on each row then `SUM` Col5 for the total.

Comment: Yes this is a solution. but I don't want to change the table, because it will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=SUMIF(A3:A10,"<12500",A3:A10)+SUMIF(A3:B10,">12500",C3:C10)
```

not included anything for equal too though..:) but just change > to >=

Comment: This formula give me really the total I want, but there is not always 12500 in the Col3. How you can modify it so it can work whatever is the number in Col3?